# List/Array of strings to numpy float array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am new to scikit learn and numpy. How can I represent my dataset made of list/array of strings eg

```
[["aa bb","a","bbb","à"], [bb cc","c","ddd","à"], ["kkk","a","","a"]]
```

to a numpy array of dtype float?

Comment: whaat ??? convert  a string to a float ? And btw, it has nothing to do with sklearn

Comment: Well, maybe I haven't used the right terms but @datawrestler understood my question and has given a very useful suggestion. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for is a numeric representation of your words. You can use gensim and map each word to a token id and from that create your numpy arrays as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from gensim import corpora 

toconvert = [["aa bb","a","bbb","à"], ["bb", "cc","c","ddd","à"], ["kkk","a","","a"]]

# convert your list of lists into token id's. For example, 'aa bb' could be represented as a 2, a as a 1, etc.
tdict = corpora.Dictionary(toconvert)

# given nested structure, you can append nested numpy arrays
newlist = []
for l in toconvert:
    tmplist = []
    for word in l:
        # append to intermediate list the id for the given word under observation
        tmplist.append(tdict.token2id[word])
    # convert to numpy array and append to main list
    newlist.append(np.array(tmplist).astype(float)) # type float

print(newlist) # desired output: [array([ 2.,  0.,  1.,  0.]), array([ 5.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  0.]), array([ 7.,  0.,  8.,  0.])]

# and to see what id's represent which strings:
tdict[0] # 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks @datawrestler for your answer you provided. It is quite useful.